# Top and Bottom in the same query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I need to make a ssrs-report that shows the best and the worst customer depending on how much they've spent. In my report i would like to represent the gap between the Top 1 and Bottom customer, within one chart. My problem is that it's impossible for me to get these values within the same dataset/query. 
This is my results from a query(see code below). I would like to, with maybe union all or something, get the same result from only one query. Or is there a easier way with e.g. Visual Studio to represent these values. Top N, Bottom N filters perhaps? If so please show me a way or "best practice" cuz i haven't figured it out yet. thx.

Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1
        dimcustomer.FirstName ,
        SUM(FactInternetSales.OrderQuantity * UnitPrice)
FROM    DimCustomer
        INNER JOIN FactInternetSales ON FactInternetSales.CustomerKey = DimCustomer.CustomerKey
GROUP BY FirstName
ORDER BY SUM(FactInternetSales.OrderQuantity * UnitPrice) DESC

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1
        dimcustomer.FirstName ,
        SUM(FactInternetSales.SalesAmount)
FROM    DimCustomer
        INNER JOIN FactInternetSales ON FactInternetSales.CustomerKey = DimCustomer.CustomerKey
GROUP BY FirstName
ORDER BY SUM(FactInternetSales.SalesAmount) DESC
```

Two result sets:

```
               FirstName |  SalesAmount
               Morgan       145044,5816

               ------------------------

               FirstName |  SalesAmount
               Dave         3.99
```

Comment: why UNION isn't working for you?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: I would stick with a SQL solution - SSRS Filtering, Expressions etc are probably not capable of meeting this requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The union operator doesn't like the order by clause so you can restructure slightly

```
  with CustomersOrders as
  (
  select dimcustomer.FirstName, sum(FactInternetSales.OrderQuantityUnitPrice) Total
      from DimCustomer 
        inner join FactInternetSales on FactInternetSales.CustomerKey = DimCustomer.CustomerKey 
      group by FirstName
  )
  select *
    from
    (
    select top 1 *
      from CustomersOrders
      order by Total desc
    ) a
  union all
  select *
    from
    (  
    select top 1 *
      from CustomersOrders
      order by Total
    ) b
```

Comment: TY! Really helped me out here. Forgot about the CTE. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can UNION these queries, and add another column "CustomerType" to queries with values - TopCustomer & BottomCustomer correspondingly to distinguish the customer type.